# Working on a project but keep getting errors

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to run a python project but I keep getting this error

**Exception in Tkinter callback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\davide\Desktop\Python Invetment Game\Main.py", line 115,     in     createb
        create = tkinter.Button(createb, text="Create Business")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2197, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2120, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2098, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
  AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

could anyone help me http://pastebin.com/qDv7R1tA

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Reduce it down to the smallest amount possible. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

This is your function `createb`:

```
def createb():
    creator = tkinter.Tk()
    creator.geometry("800x768")
    creator.title("Pyhton Business Creator")
    global Type
    Type = 0
    def HD1():
        global Type
        Type = 1
        global owner
        owner = 1
    if cash > 12500:
        HD2 = tkinter.Button(createb, text="Hairdresser Business")
        HD2.pack
    create = tkinter.Button(createb, text="Create Business")
    creator.mainloop()
```

You are trying to create a button on a function, which of course is impossible.
So instead of:

```
HD2 = tkinter.Button(createb, text="Hairdresser Business")
create = tkinter.Button(createb, text="Create Business")
```

Type:

```
HD2 = tkinter.Button(creator, text="Hairdresser Business")
create = tkinter.Button(creator, text="Create Business")
```

BTW, it should be `HD2.pack()` instead of `HD2.pack`.